# Python: Combine set and array

Tags: python, arrays, set, data-mining

I have an a set 'items' containing unique int32 numbers. I want to merge this with an array frequency. Both of them are of same size.

```
table = {'items': items, 'values': frequency}
C1 = pd.DataFrame(data=table)
```

By expected output is something like this (First column containing set and second column containing the frequencies:

{A,B}   | 25

{E,F,G} | 17

{D}     | 5

But I'm getting an error: **TypeError: Set type is unordered**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What exactly are your inputs? Note, I don't really understand the *point* of your dataframe, why use `pandas` here at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t combine them in the way that you want to. What you probably want to use is a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

uids = defaultdict(int)

raw = get_data()

for uid in raw:
    uids[uid] += 1
```

This will produce a dictionary that has a mapping of all the uids to the frequency of that uid.

If you need a mapping of frequency to all the uids that occur with frequency you can then reverse the trick.

```
frequencies = defaultdict(set)

for uid, frequency in uids.items():
    frequencies[frequency].add(uid)
```

Comment: this works great, but a collections.Counter object will do this even more efficiently.

Comment: `Counter` doesn’t have a default key value. And it doesn’t seem they need any of the other functionality of `Counter`.

Comment: "Counter doesn’t have a default key value. And it doesn’t seem they need any of the other functionality of Counter" But you don't *need* the default key value. You just need `Counter(raw)`